# Maximum subspace of Lp space which has Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

What is the maximum subspace of  Lp (p>2) space which has Fourier transform? Is it Schwartz class or bigger than it?

Comment: Presumably the largest subspace is $L^1\cap L^p$. The former guarantees that you can actually do the integral and have it make sense, the latter is self explanatory.

Comment: I feel like it would be larger than $L^1\cap L^p$ since we just need $f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}$ to be integrable for each $\xi$. Of course $f \in L^1$ guarantees this, but I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: L2 intersects Lp may be greater than L1 intersects Lp.

Comment: Let me ask one more question. Why we can't extend Fourier transform to all of Lp from Schwartz class?

Comment: We can, but the result will only be a tempered distribution, not necessarily a function.

Comment: @mathworker21 the condition that that function is integrable is exactly that $f$ is in $L^1$. There is no wiggle room.

Comment: I am not getting that why you are insisting on integrable functions. We can have the definition Fourier transform on L2. @mathworker21

Answer (score 1):

The largest subspace is $L^1 \cap L^p$ since we need $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{-2\pi ix \xi}dx$ to exist for each $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $f \in L^1$, then the integral exists, and we need $f \in L^1$, which can be seen by taking $\xi = 0$ for example. Since you wanted it defined on $L^p$ as well, we need $f$ to be in $L^p$ as well; hence $L^1 \cap L^p$.

The issue for defining it directly on $L^2$ is that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi x}dx$ might not converge if we only know $f \in L^2$, similar to how $\int_1^\infty (\frac{1}{x})^2dx$ exists but not $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx$ does not. We can define the fourier transform of $f \in L^2$ as the limit of the fourier transform of Schwarz functions approximating $f$ (note schwarz functions are in $L^1$ so taking the fourier transform of them makes sense). This implicitly uses the fact that the set of Schwarz functions is dense in $L^2$.